# register device at run time

Tags: iphone

1. In the App ID section of the Program Portal, locate the App ID you wish to use with the Apple Push Notification service. Only App IDs with a specific bundle ID can be used with the APNs. You cannot use a “wild-card” application ID. You must see “Available” under the Apple Push Notification service column to register this App ID and configure a certificate for this App ID.
2. Click the ‘Configure’ link next to your desired App ID.
3. In the Configure App ID page, check the Enable Push Notification Services box and click the Configure button. Clicking this button launches the APNs Assistant, which guides you through the next series of steps that create your App ID specific Client SSL certificate.
4. Download the Client SSL certificate file to your download location. Navigate to that location and double-click the certificate file (which has an extension of cer) to install it in your keychain.
5. When you are finished, click Done in the APNS Assistant.
6. Double-clicking the file launches Keychain Access. Make sure you install the certificate in your login keychain on the computer you are using for provider development. The APNs SSL certificate should be installed on your notification server.
7. When you finish these steps you are returned to the Configure App ID page of the iPhone Dev Center portal. The certificate should be badged with a green circle and the label “Enabled”.
8. To complete the APNs set-up process, you will need to create a new provisioning profile containing your APNs-enabled App ID.

IS it posssible to do theses steps through code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this completes only the certificate part. you need to implement code in your app and also you need a server(SSL supported).what you have to do after generating certificate is register your device for remote notification.you'll find that how to do this in Remote notification guide.then you'll get device token send the device token to your server and your server will forward the device token+message(you want to show on device) to APNS.APNS will send the notification to the device.also you need to show certificate when sending device token from your server to APNs.read the whole Remote Notifications Guide carefully.